# URL's strict redirection (.htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm using a subdomain which utilize a same root folder as my main domain. The subdomain (once displayed) should redirect to a specific page of the main domain.

Currently the following code is set in my subdomain's .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?inspexio.amtsystems\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://amtsystems.net/inspexio/$1 [L,NE,P]
```

Basically the subdomain here is **"inspexio.amtsystems.net"** which should be used by visitors and the content of the main domain's page `https://amtsystems.net/inspexio` must be taken. It works but when you're accessing other pages than `inspexio.amtsystems.net/inspexio` they will be also displayed, however I would like to not redirect in other cases, only the targeted page `https://amtsystems.net/inspexio` must be rewrited as `inspexio.amtsystems.net`.

How to use a strict redirection?

Another question: how to avoid ranking issues with Google or Bing on SEO and to add the 301 redirects to the existing code?

Comment: Make your RewriteRule match only that specific path, instead of "everything" - `RewriteRule ^inspexio$ https://...`

Comment: Hello and thanks. I tried your solution, by adding this:

RewriteRule ^inspexio$ https://amtsystems.net/ [L,NE,P]

But all links are always displayed, it didn't take into account the /inspexio path :(

Comment: _"But all links are always displayed"_ - can't tell what that is supposed to mean, please clarify.

Comment: If the visitors access only `http://nspexio.amtsystems.net` without any path, then it of course makes little sense to try and check for the path originally matching `inspexio/` already. But I really can't tell what _exactly_ you are trying to set up here.

Comment: Hi. Ok I'll try to explain one more time my needs:
Visitors by accessing the inspexio.amtsystems.net will see the content of amtsystems.net page. But in the browser the inspexio.amtsystems.net will be shown wherever happens. It's ok.

Comment: The problem is that being on inspexio.amtsystems.net and accessing any links fom there, the content of amtsystems.net (any page) will be displayed, however I prefer to limit it to amtsystems.net/inspexio page ONLY...

Comment: Okay, so you want to do this for the root path only, but then any link pointing to `inspexio.amtsystems.net/anything` should not be affected? Then you need to use a RewriteRule pattern that only allows for an empty path, `^$`

Comment: Hello, I tried to add ^$ to the RewriteRule as: RewriteRule ^$ https://amtsystems.net/inspexio/$1 [L,NE,P] but no result, when accessing the inspexio.amtsystems.net page, the main page of the root is showing and not the /inspexio page...